# Keep inline-block element on one side in place while scrolling, without position: fixed?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How would you get an element/div to stay in place (WITHOUT position: fixed;) while you scroll? (Actually, this page is a perfect example. The left side with the buttons do not move, while you can scroll this page where the content of this/my post is.)

Say, you have two divs, both are inline-block. The left div you want to stay in place. You only want to allow scrolling on the right div. (different tracks). position: fixed; doesn't really give me the result I'm looking for. Open to any solutions in CSS, vanilla JS, and/or jQuery. Here's some code that I've been trying:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    border-right: 2px solid $blueBorder;
    padding: 0.5%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.right {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 0.5%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#left').css('top', $(this).scrollTop() + "px");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with pure css. As you pointed out, this page is an example. If you dig into it with your browser dev tools you will find something similar to this below.

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 40px;
  
}

.header {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.left {
  flex-basis: 300px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 40px
}

.right {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}

.footer {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pad {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header pad">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="sticky pad">
        Left
        <div style="height:60vh;"></div>
        Left Bottom
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right pad">
      Right
      <div style="height:200vh;"></div>
      Right Bottom
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer pad">
    Footer
    <div style="height:30vh;"></div>
    Footer Bottom
  </div>
</body>
```

Another way I have done things in the past would be to scroll just the right content div and include the footer over there (not full width). Like below.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
  flex-basis: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.right {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}

.right-content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.footer {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pad {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header pad outline">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left pad outline">
      Left
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="right-content pad outline">
        Right
        <div style="height:200vh;"></div>
        Right End
      </div>
      <div class="footer pad outline">
        Footer
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Actually digging into the current SO page is done a little differently, utilizing padding on the body along with fixed positioning of the header. As well as using 'sticky' positioning of the nav bar on the left. All of this results a slightly different outcome, leaving the scrolling done at the window level, as well as allowing for a full width footer that is scrolled into view.

Comment: Out of the couple of answers here, this works the best (I simply grabbed the heights of everything above my container, added them and dynamically set the padding-top of the body, so it's not underneath my navbar). The only issue I'm having, my footer seems to ignore the body and just overlaps it, so 90% of the page is just... footer. (My footer includes a few items that take up a decent amount of height)

Comment: I cleaned up my previous example as well as added an example that is closer to SO's (as discussed in the previous comment). Maybe looking that over will help. Otherwise I suggest creating a simple version of what you have going on either here or something like codepen.io etc to work through.

Answer (score 0):

Use sematic elements like `section` and `aside` tags in html instead of div so it will make more friendly.

Use [w3](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp) as reference

Answer (score 0):

What's cool is you can just inspect this website using Right-Clicking and just look at StackOverflow's Code. They're going the Sticky Method, I've done a barebones version below

```css
#contents{
  display: flex;
}

#left{
  background-color:yellow;
  position: relative !important;
  width:150px;
}
#sticky{
  position: sticky;
  background-color:red;
  top: 0;
}
#right{
  background-color:blue;
  position: relative !important;
  width:150px;
  height:650px;
}
```

```html
<div id="contents">
  <div id="left">
    <div id="sticky">
      top<br>
      blah<br>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    1<br>
    2<br>
    3<br>
    4<br>
    5<br>
    6<br>
    7<br>
    8<br>
    9<br>
    10<br>
    11<br>
    12<br>
    13<br>
    14<br>
    15<br>
    16<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

edit, grammar/spelling

Comment: If you set the body margin to 0 (Browsers seems to default it to 8px) it gets rid of the unwanted initial scroll of everything.